# Wordpress Custom Taxonomy Values not displaying in menu

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I have created a new custom taxonomy, and the values I enter for this taxonomy are visible/saved in the edit post area here:

[image]

However, they do not seem to save/display when I click on the 'Custom Post' button in the admin menu, where you can make quick edits:

[image]

Here's the code in my functions.php file:

```
function create_seamstitch_taxonomy() {
$labels = array(
    'name'                       => 'Seam Stitching',
    'singular_name'              => 'Seam Stitching',
    'menu_name'                  => 'Seam Stitching',
    'all_items'                  => 'All Seam Stitching',
    'parent_item'                => 'Parent Seam Stitching',
    'parent_item_colon'          => 'Parent Seam Stitching:',
    'new_item_name'              => 'New Seam Stitching Name',
    'add_new_item'               => 'Add New Seam Stitching',
    'edit_item'                  => 'Edit Seam Stitching',
    'update_item'                => 'Update Seam Stitching',
    'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate Seam Stitchings with commas',
    'search_items'               => 'Search Seam Stitching',
    'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Add or remove Seam Stitchings',
    'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Choose from the most used Seam Stitchings',
    'not_found'                  => 'Seam Stitching Not Found',
);
$args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => false,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
);
register_taxonomy( 'seamstitching', 'buttonup', $args );
}

// Hook into the 'init' action
add_action( 'init', 'create_seamstitch_taxonomy', 0 );
```

Does anyone know why this would happen? This also seems to not work at the moment in my posts:

```
<?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'seam_stitching', 'Seam Stitching: ', ', ', ''         ); ?>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You mention a custom post type - do you also have a custom post type where you are expecting this taxonomy to be available? If so, does your custom post type have this in the configuration array: `'taxonomies'     => array('seamstitching'),`

Comment: Yes, there's actually two others added in there as well, and the others work perfectly! I should have also mentioned that I screwed up and used a capital letter in the name at first. It's lowercase now, but could that have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I changed the name of the taxonomy and re-entered the data, and everything is working normally now. This issue may have stemmed from first registering the taxonomy using an uppercase first letter in the name, then switching to lower. I changed it completely and it seems to work now.